# can i cleanup buffer for some specified database instead of the entire sql server

Tags: sql-server, caching, dbcc

from what i know, if i execute 'DBCC FREEPROCCACHE' and 'DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS', the buffer of entire server will be cleanup.
i wonder if there's anyway to cleanup buffer of specified database only. therefore, query for other databases will not be affected.

Comment: No, you cannot - those are system-/server-wide commands, and there's no equivalent on a per-database basis

Answer (score 5):

You can clear all execution plans from a single database using `DBCC FLUSHPROCINDB(<db_id>)`. I'm not aware of any similar command to clear specific pages from the buffer cache.

However, you **can** set the database offline momentarily and then back online to clear both plan and buffer caches for a database if the situation allows for this.

Answer (score 0):

Not a possibility with `FREEPROCCACHE` or `DBCC FREEPROCCACHE`

As per msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc293622.aspx

> DBCC FREEPROCCACHE This command removes all cached plans from memory
>   DBCC FLUSHPROCINDB (`<dbid>`) This command allows you to specify a
>   particular database id, and then clears all plans from that particular
>   database.

db id can be fetched this way

```
DECLARE @intDBID INT;
SET @intDBID = (SELECT [dbid] 
                FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
                WHERE name = 'AdventureWorks');

-- Flush the procedure cache for one database only
DBCC FLUSHPROCINDB (@intDBID);
```